# React Bootstrap Modal closes on button click

Tags: javascript, meteor-accounts, react-bootstrap

I am new to Meteor and React BootStrap. I am trying to register a user with Meteor from a React bootstrap modal. My user registration code works just fine, but my modal closes as soon as the async call to meteor Accounts.createUser is executed. If i remove the call to Accounts.createUser my modal stays open.

I want the modal to remain open in case there are any errors like the email used by the user for signing up already exists, and i can show the messages next to the modal fields itself. I can close the modal if there are no errors once the async call completes.

Any help to achieve the same is appreciated. Please see below the two React components i use to accomplish this. I use login control as a separate component so that i can reuse the core code in other places where the login screen does not need to be a modal. (I am still in a testing mode, so the modal label says Signin but i am actually doing a create user).

```
var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
var Modal = ReactBootstrap.Modal;

LoginModal = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return { show: false };
    },

    modalClosing(){
        this.setState({ show: false });
    },

    render() {
        let close = () => this.modalClosing();
        let open = () => this.setState({ show: true});
        return (
            <div>
                <Button bsStyle="primary"
                        bsSize="small"
                        onClick={open}>
                    Login
                </Button>

                <div className="modal-container">
                    <Modal show={this.state.show}
                        onHide={close}
                        container={this}
                        animation={true}
                        onRequestHide={close}
                        backdrop="static"
                        dialogClassName="custom-modal"
                        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title">
                        <Modal.Header closeButton>
                            <Modal.Title className="h2" id="contained-modal-title">Sign in</Modal.Title>
                        </Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Body>
                            <LoginControl showCloseButton="true" onCloseClick={close}/>
                        </Modal.Body>
                    </Modal>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
var ButtonInput = ReactBootstrap.ButtonInput;
var Input = ReactBootstrap.Input;
var Label = ReactBootstrap.Label;

LoginControl = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            disabled: true,
            userStyle: null,
            pwdStyle: null,
            btnStyle: "primary"
        };
    },

    resetValidation() {
        this.setState({
            disabled: true,
            userStyle: null,
            pwdStyle: null,
            btnStyle: "primary"
        });
    },

    validationState() {
        let length = this.refs.input.getValue().length;
        let btnStyle = 'danger';

        if (length > 6) btnStyle = 'success';
        else if (length > 4) btnStyle = 'warning';

        let disabled = btnStyle !== 'success';

        return { btnStyle, disabled };
    },

    showCloseButton(){
        if (this.props.showCloseButton) {
            return (<Button className="pull-right signin-modal-closebtn" bsSize="large" onClick={this.tryLogin}>Close</Button>);
        }
        return null;
    },

    handleChange(input, e) {
        let validationState = this.validationState();
        if (validationState != null) {
            let value = e.target.value;
            let btnStyle = validationState.btnStyle;
            if (validationState.btnStyle === "success") {
                btnStyle = null;
            }
            else {
                if (input == "user") {
                    btnStyle = this.state.userStyle;
                }
                else if (input == "pwd") {
                    btnStyle = this.state.pwdStyle;
                }
            }
            if (input === "user") {
                this.setState({ user: value, userStyle: btnStyle });
            }
            else if (input === "pwd") {
                this.setState({ pwd: value, pwdStyle: btnStyle });
            }
        }
        this.setState(validationState);
    },

    login (){
        Accounts.createUser({
            email: this.state.user,
            userName: this.state.user,
            password: this.state.pwd,
            profile: null
        }, function (error) {
            if (error) {
                if (error.error === 403.1) {
                    this.setState({ user: this.state.user, userStyle: "error", pwdStyle: "error", validationMessage :error.message});
                }
                else if (error.error === 403.2) {
                    this.setState({ pwd: this.state.pwd, userStyle: "error", pwdStyle: null, validationMessage: error.message });
                }
            }
            else {
                this.props.onCloseClick();
                //Router.go('/');
            }
        });
    },

    tryLogin(args) {
        //args.preventDefault();
        this.login(args);
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Label class="sr-only">{this.state.validationMessage}</Label>
                <Input type="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email address" ref="input" bsSize="large" bsStyle={this.state.userStyle} required autofocus onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,"user")}/>
                <Input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" ref="input" bsSize="large" placeholder="Password" required onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,"pwd")}/>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <Button bsStyle={this.state.btnStyle} className="pull-right" bsSize="large" disabled={this.state.disabled} onClick={this.tryLogin}>Sign in</Button>
                    {this.showCloseButton()}
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" /> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: You forgot to bind this.tryLogin to the component in onClick

Comment: @madoxx22, Thanks for looking into this post. As far as i know, react does this automatically, so you don't have to bind the call.

Comment: you are right, a thought you are using es6 classes